# Tornado iframe src error

Tags: python, tornado

Tornado web page I want to add my google maps. But iframe does not work.

See example:
[example http://imgim.com/ttnak.png](http://imgim.com/ttnak.png)

How to embed iframe code my project?

**My maps var (in var.py)**

```
maps = '<iframe src="">'
```

after

I edit **"nerede.html"** file, Add this code => `{{ maps }}`

Code it's work but iframe not work. What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all output to template [is passed through the `xhtml_escape` method](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.settings), the [result of which](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/escape.html#tornado.escape.xhtml_escape) is what you are seeing.  It will take your HTML, and escape it - so instead of `<iframe src=>`, what you get is `&lt;iframe src=&gt;`.

To stop this, use the `{% raw %}` tag, as detailed in the [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html).  Your template should be `{% raw maps %}`.

Comment: Thanks i solved problem:

`<iframe src="{{ maps }}" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>` it's run :)